# How can I encode UTF-8 to create case-insensitive ASCII filenames?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, filesystems, ascii

I have a list of UTF-8 strings, most of which are ASCII, but some of which contain Korean/Japanese characters. I want to create a file associated with each string. To avoid any problems with the filesystem not supporting these weird characters, I want to somehow encode each UTF-8 string into ASCII to generate its filename. The generated ASCII should be case-insensitive and all-lowercase to avoid problems with Windows' case-insensitive filesystem. (So e.g. Base64 encoding along would not work.) What are some ways to do this?

Comment: Look up [punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode). Percent-encoding should also work although might cause problems if you use batch files.

Comment: urlencode could help. It translate nearly all characters outside alpha-numeric-dashes, so maybe it is too much, but it can do a bijective translation. Then you could use one translate character (but still ascii) as escape (as prefix of lowercase) and upcase all the string.  But if you want to be most compatible as possible, you will have filename length problem. Do a 8.3 filename and a file with mapping.

Comment: Some variation of [Base36 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36) looks like it should meet your requirements.  You'd have to treat the input UTF-8 as an array of integer values.